# What does the @ sign mean before a variable in scala?

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

In some documentation I came across the `@` sign before a variable. What does this sign mean?

Here is the code in the documentation:

```
class Book(val id: Long, 
           var title: String,
           @Column("AUTHOR_ID")
           var authorId: Long,
           var coAuthorId: Option[Long]) {

  def this() = this(0,"",0,Some(0L))
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This means that it is an [`annotation`](http://docs.scala-lang.org/tutorials/tour/annotations.html). In this specific scenario, it is actually an alias for an annotation if you look at the [documentation](http://squeryl.org/api/index.html#org.squeryl.annotations.package).

> type **Column** = org.squeryl.annotations.**ColumnBase** @scala.annotation.meta.field
>
> **ColumnBase** extends Annotation with Annotation with ClassfileAnnotation

Answer (score 1):

It is a relational mapping:

```
 @Column(name="sql_column_name")
```

that defines a table column name that is different to the field name:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/cheatsheet/model